# How to get all id's from list of dictionaries python

Tags: python

I have below result from json file. I want to get all id's from the list of dictionaries

```
result = { 
           "response": [{
             "1d": 1, 
             "name": "jhon"
           },  
           {
             "1d": 2, 
             "name": "tom"
           }, 
           {
             "1d": 3, 
             "name": "peter"
           }
         ]}
```

expected result: `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: `[x['1d'] for x in result['response']]`

Comment: "want" should not be used if you haven't tried anything. What have you tried ? At least as seen from description, we can't say you have tried or researched well.

Comment: Please, avoid asking low-effort question, post some code of what you have tried, the community role is to help, not to do your homework for you, consider reading this guide about asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: print ([value['1d'] for value in result['response'] ])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print ([value['1d'] for value in result['response'] ])
```

Comment: This is showing up in the low-quality answers queue, but does answer the Question! Can you add a line about how this works?